# opens a box within page when link is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

I don't know where to start and what to search. I have two links in my HTML file. I want a box within the page to appear below the link when the link above is clicked and when I clicked the second link, the first box will disappear and the other box below the second link will appear. It is like a sliding box as the link is clicked. What is the code/post for this? Thank you so much!

Comment: Provide your html code.

Comment: Hi! I am starting my code and I don't know where to start since I can't find the 'right searchable tutorial'  on Google for this.

Answer (score 1):

May be called a content switcher or a tabs widget. Here's a simple way of doing it in CSS.

```css
.box {
  display: none;
}
.box:target {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#one">one</a> <a href="#two">two</a>

<div id="one" class="box">box one</div>
<div id="two" class="box">box two</div>
```

And here's a way to do it in JS

```js
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a'),
    boxes = document.getElementsByClassName('box');
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  links[i].addEventListener('click',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = this.getAttribute('href').replace('#','');
    for (var j = 0; j < boxes.length; j++) {
      boxes[j].classList.remove('active');
    }
    document.getElementById(url).classList.add('active');
  })
}
```

```css
.box {
  display: none;
}
.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#one">one</a> <a href="#two">two</a>

<div id="one" class="box">box one</div>
<div id="two" class="box">box two</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I'm looking for. I'll start from this. :)

Comment: @AllenDelaCruz np! updated my answer with a simple JS solution, too.

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand you but i guess you want some thing like this :

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById('myDIV');
    if (x.style.display === 'none') {
        x.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        x.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

```css
#myDIV {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 50px 0;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: lightblue;
    margin-top:20px;
}
```

```html
<p>Click the "Try it" button to toggle between hiding and showing the DIV element:</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<div id="myDIV">
This is my DIV element.
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I am looking for! :) I'll start with this. Thank you much!